# Set the number of lines of the title React

Tags: reactjs

How can I edit the title lines by setting it to two lines?
In the current situation, each word is shown on one line. Instead, I wish the first word "broadcaster" was on one line, while the other "control panels" on the bottom line.
This is my code.

```js
function IndexHeader() {
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="page-header section-dark"
        style={{
          backgroundImage:
            "url(" + require("assets/img/background.jpg") + ")"
        }}
      >
        <div className="filter" />
        <div className="content-center">
          <Container>
            <div className="title-brand">
              <h1 className="presentation-title">Broadcaster control panel</h1>
            </div>
            <h2 className="presentation-subtitle text-center">
              Pannello di controllo degli spot AdEx
            </h2>
          </Container>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default IndexHeader;
```

Thanks in advance to those who can help me!

Comment: What about adding a `<br/>`?

Comment: use two headings or `<br/>`

Comment: <h1 className="presentation-title">Broadcaster <br/>control panel</h1>

Comment: I solved it by changing the classname. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
<div className="title-brand">
   <h1 className="presentation-title">Broadcaster</h1>
   <h1 className="presentation-title">control panel</h1>
</div>
```

or

```
<div className="title-brand">
   <h1 className="presentation-title">Broadcaster <br/> control panel </h1>
</div>
```

and you can handle that using CSS.